# Systray in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: qt, ubuntu, systray

I have a daemon called foo. My conf file /etc/init/foo.conf starts the foo daemon as root.

The foo daemon calls system function to execute the other application which show tray icon using Qt.

I run the following command to enable the Systray for applications in Ubuntu:

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`

However, the schema's gone from 13.04.

Despite founding the solution that uses a PPA that comes with to re-enable the systray whitelist, I can't apply that in my project.

Is there any way to do?

Answer (score 0):

Systray whitelisting was ridiculously insecure and Canonical removed support for it.

A patch is available to restore the old behavior: https://askubuntu.com/questions/330272/help-with-system-tray-whitelisting